# Facebook feed dialog who will see

Tags: facebook, dialog, feed

I'm developing an site which uses Facebook Feed dialog. I'm wondering about the sandbox mode. If i turn that of (go live with the app/disbable) will there be any notification in my news feed/timeline?

I have to know since i want to test it before going public and making people aware of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to your Facebook App settings, it it said for the "Sandbox mode":

> if enabled, only app developers will be able to use app

If you deploy your application on live your should disable the sandbox mode. This mode is only for allowing developers to test.

Comment: Yes, but my main concern is that will there be any form of notification on my timeline when i deploy the app? Kind of a silly quesion but still, Facebook usually shares everything that happens there so..

Comment: For example in timeline: NAME has created/deployed APP NAME

Comment: No I never had notifications published on my profile. Notifications sent by Facebook (e.g. new API breaking change) are only sent to you (as a notification in your top main bar) and never shared with others.